# Passing variable value in php array

Tags: php, arrays

I have array in php like:

```
if ($_GET['id1'] == "machine-category") {
    $table['cols'] = array(
        array('label' => 'category', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('label' => 'count', 'type' => 'string')
    );
}
```

I want to pass various value in category, tried:

```
if ($_GET['id1'] == "machine-category") {
    $table['cols'] = array(
        array("'".
            "label".
            "'".
            " => . ".
            "'".explode($GET['id1'], "-")[1].
            "', '".
            "type'".
            " => '".
            "string".
            "'"),
        array('label' => 'count', 'type' => 'string')
    );
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Can anyone provide the solution for same?

Comment: Could you provide more details on how, exactly, it is not working?

Comment: explode($GET['id1'], "-")[1] not permitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish.  Perhaps you're saying that if your `$_GET['id1']` is `machine-category`, you want a line that looks like this:

```
    array('label' => 'category', 'type' => 'string'),
```

and if you have a `$_GET['id1']` of `machine-foobar` then you want a line like this:

```
    array('label' => 'foobar', 'type' => 'string'),
```

Is that what you're asking?  In that case, try this:

```
if ($_GET['id1'] == "machine-category!") {
        $category_parts = explode('-', $_GET['id1']);
        $category = $category_parts[1];
        $table['cols'] = array(
            array('label' => $category, 'type' => 'string'),
            array('label' => 'count', 'type' => 'string')
        );
}
```